# Converting squared and cube terms into multiplication

Tags: c, sympy, evaluation

I am trying to convert a big expression from sage into valid C code using ccode() from sympy. However, my expression has many squared and cube terms. As pow(x,2) is far slower than x*x, I'm trying to expand those terms in my expression before the conversion.
Based on [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/qaJGesRbX_0) conversation, I wrote the following code :

```
    from sympy import Symbol, Mul, Pow, pprint, Matrix, symbols
    from sympy.core import numbers


    def pow_to_mul(expr):
         """
         Convert integer powers in an expression to Muls, like a**2 => a*a.
         """
         pows = list(expr.atoms(Pow))
         pows = [p for p in pows if p.as_base_exp()[1]>=0]
         if any(not e.is_Integer for b, e in (i.as_base_exp() for i in pows)):

              raise ValueError("A power contains a non-integer exponent")
         repl = zip(pows, (Mul(*[b]*e,evaluate=False) for b,e in (i.as_base_exp() for i in pows)))
         return expr.subs(repl)
```

It partially works, but fails as long  as the power is argument of a multiplication:

```
    >>>_=var('x')
    >>>print pow_to_mul((x^3+2*x^2)._sympy_())
    2*x**2 + x*x*x
    >>>print pow_to_mul((x^2/(1+x^2)+(1-x^2)/(1+x^2))._sympy_())
    x**2/(x*x + 1) - (x*x - 1)/(x*x + 1)
```

Why? And how can I change that ?
Thank you very much,

Comment: What exactly fails? `+(1-x^2)/(1+x^2)` is the same as `-(x*x - 1)/(x*x + 1)`.

Comment: And in the first example, `x^3+2*x^2` is the same as `2*x**2 + x*x*x`. The sequence was switched and the operator style, but they are mathematically the same. It is unclear what you are asking. `**` is sometimes used for "to the power" to distinguish it from `^` which can be "exclusive-or".

Comment: The problem is that ccode(x * x)  returns x * x, while ccode(x^2) or ccode(x**2) returns pow(x, 2). Once in a c program, the latter is really not optimal. Hence I'd expect 2 * x * x + x * x * x for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with `-ffast-math` the compiler will do this optimization for you. If you are using an ancient compiler or cannot affect the level of optimization used in the build process you may pass a user defined function to ccode (using SymPy master branch):

```
>>> ccode(x**97 + 4*x**7 + 5*x**3 + 3**pi, user_functions={'Pow': [
...   (lambda b, e: e.is_Integer and e < 42, lambda b, e: '*'.join([b]*int(e))),
...   (lambda b, e: not e.is_Integer, 'pow')]})
'pow(x, 97) + 4*x*x*x*x*x*x*x + 5*x*x*x + pow(3, M_PI)'
```

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for. However, the lambda which shall give the string is not evaluated so that your example's output is :

        `pow(x, 97) + 4*<function <lambda> at 0x8bc791b4>(x, 7) + 5*<function <lambda> at 0x8bc791b4>(x, 3) + pow(3, M_PI)`

Comment: What commit is your master branch at? You need 84db5141 or later.

Comment: OK, that was the problem. I don't know what bad command I typed, but sympy had been updated only locally. I learned git recently sorry.
And thank you very much for your help !