# Generate C code with Sympy. Replace Pow(x,2) by x*x

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, code-generation, codegen

I am generating C code with sympy the using the Common Subexpression Elimination (CSE) routine and the ccode printer.

However, I would like to have powered expressions as (x*x) instead of pow(x,2).

Anyway to do this?

Example:

```
import sympy as sp
a= sp.MatrixSymbol('a',3,3)
b=sp.Matrix(a)*sp.Matrix(a)

res = sp.cse(b)

lines = []
     
for tmp in res[0]:
    lines.append(sp.ccode(tmp[1], tmp[0]))

for i,result in enumerate(res[1]):
    lines.append(sp.ccode(result,"result_%i"%i))
```

Will output:

```
x0[0] = a[0];
x0[1] = a[1];
x0[2] = a[2];
x0[3] = a[3];
x0[4] = a[4];
x0[5] = a[5];
x0[6] = a[6];
x0[7] = a[7];
x0[8] = a[8];
x1 = x0[0];
x2 = x0[1];
x3 = x0[3];
x4 = x2*x3;
x5 = x0[2];
x6 = x0[6];
x7 = x5*x6;
x8 = x0[4];
x9 = x0[7];
x10 = x0[5];
x11 = x0[8];
x12 = x10*x9;
result_0[0] = pow(x1, 2) + x4 + x7;
result_0[1] = x1*x2 + x2*x8 + x5*x9;
result_0[2] = x1*x5 + x10*x2 + x11*x5;
result_0[3] = x1*x3 + x10*x6 + x3*x8;
result_0[4] = x12 + x4 + pow(x8, 2);
result_0[5] = x10*x11 + x10*x8 + x3*x5;
result_0[6] = x1*x6 + x11*x6 + x3*x9;
result_0[7] = x11*x9 + x2*x6 + x8*x9;
result_0[8] = pow(x11, 2) + x12 + x7;
```

Best Regards

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173019/converting-squared-and-cube-terms-into-multiplication

Answer (score 4):

There is a function called `create_expand_pow_optimization` that creates a wrapper to optimise your expressions in this respect. It takes as an argument the highest power it will replace by explicit multiplications.

The wrapper returns an `UnevaluatedExpr` that is protected against automatic simplifications that would revert this change.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.codegen.rewriting import create_expand_pow_optimization

expand_opt = create_expand_pow_optimization(3)

a = sp.Matrix(sp.MatrixSymbol('a',3,3))
res = sp.cse(a@a)

for i,result in enumerate(res[1]):
    print(sp.ccode(expand_opt(result),"result_%i"%i))
```

Finally, be aware that for sufficiently high optimisation levels, your compiler will take care of this (and is probably better at this).

Comment: That function appears to be interesting! However, I was not able to make work in the `user_functions` of `ccode `. Additionally, it appears to only work for cases of symbol ^ integer. If I have: `sp.ccode(expand_opt (a+b)**2)` it will give me `'pow(a + b, 2)`

Comment: That should be `sp.ccode(expand_opt((a+b)**2))`, but even then it does not work. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I created [an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/20753) on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the [code printer](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html), and only change the one function you want different. You'd need to investigate [the original sympy code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/9e8f62e059d83178c1d8a1e19acac5473bdbf1c1/sympy/codegen/cfunctions.py) to find the correct function names and default implementation, so you can make sure you don't make errors. With a bit of care, the needed brackets can be generated automatically exact when and where they are needed.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.printing.c import C99CodePrinter
from sympy.printing.precedence import precedence
from sympy.abc import x

class CustomCodePrinter(C99CodePrinter):
    def _print_Pow(self, expr):
        PREC = precedence(expr)
        if expr.exp == 2:
            return '({0} * {0})'.format(self.parenthesize(expr.base, PREC))
        else:
            return super()._print_Pow(expr)

default_printer = C99CodePrinter().doprint
custom_printer = CustomCodePrinter().doprint

expressions = [x, (2 + x) ** 2, x ** 3, x ** 15, sp.sqrt(5), sp.sqrt(x)**4, 1 / x, 1 / (x * x)]
print("Default: {}".format(default_printer(expressions)))
print("Custom: {}".format(custom_printer(expressions)))
```

Output:

```py
Default: [x, pow(x + 2, 2), pow(x, 3), pow(x, 15), sqrt(5), pow(x, 2), 1.0/x, pow(x, -2)]
Custom: [x, ((x + 2) * (x + 2)), pow(x, 3), pow(x, 15), sqrt(5), (x * x), 1.0/x, pow(x, -2)]
```

PS: To support a wider range of exponents, you could use e.g.

```py
class CustomCodePrinter(C99CodePrinter):
    def _print_Pow(self, expr):
        PREC = precedence(expr)
        if expr.exp in range(2, 7):
            return '*'.join([self.parenthesize(expr.base, PREC)] * int(expr.exp))
        elif expr.exp in range(-6, 0):
            return '1.0/(' + ('*'.join([self.parenthesize(expr.base, PREC)] * int(-expr.exp))) + ')'
        else:
            return super()._print_Pow(expr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I will go with the user_function approach:

As suggested in the comment above I will be using the `user_functions` functionality of sp.ccode:
Assuming we have a number like `a^3`

`sp.ccode(a**3, user_functions={'Pow': [(lambda x, y: y.is_integer, lambda x, y: '*'.join(['('+x+')']*int(y))),(lambda x, y: not y.is_integer, 'pow')]})`

should output:
`'(a)*(a)*(a)'`

In the future, I will try to improve the function to only put parenthesis when needed.

Any improvements are welcome!

Comment: You still have to check for negative powers. E.g. it goes wrong for `1/a`, `a**(-2)` or `1/(a**2+1)`. For high powers you probably want to use [exponentiation via squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which can result in a lot of speedup. (Also note that most C compilers do this kind of optimizations automatically.)